# Handling event when approving a document

Tags: sharepoint, event-handling

In SharePoint,

using an event receiver, how do we find out when a user has approved a document in a document library?

I would think it should be captured in ItemAdded or ItemAdding event.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ItemUpdated is the event receiver to use, unless you want to "override" the approval (and maybe keep the item unapproved) - in this case you should use the ItemUpdating.

To check if the item is approved you could try this code:

```
public override void ItemUpdated(SPItemEventProperties properties)
{
   if (properties.ListItem["Approval Status"] == "Approved")
   //Do Something
}
```

Hope it helps